# Complex numbers $z$ satisfying $|z−a|+|z+a| = 2|b|\Leftrightarrow |a|\le |b|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

could you help me to prove the next statement?

Show that there are complex numbers $z$ satisfying

$$|z−a|+|z+a| = 2|b| $$

if and only if $|a| \le |b|$.

I did the first implication using the triangle inequality, but I´m not able to do the second.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the first implication and what is the second one? Please show us the prove.

Comment: If you draw the complex numbers as points in the plane your equation describes what kind of figure?

Comment: @miracle173: Precisely what I used in my answer. Either great minds think alike, or it was a...miracle.

Answer (score 1):

The result is clear if $a=0$. Now suppose that $|a|\gt 0$.

We look for solutions of the shape $z=ta$ where $t$ is real. Then $|z-a|=|1-t||a|$ and $|z+a|=|1+t||a|$.  We want to show that  $|1-t|+|1+t|$ takes on all values $\ge 2$. This is clear by the Intermediate Value Theorem, since $|1-t|+|1+t|=2$ at $t=1$, and $|1-t|+|1+t|$ can be made arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this set can be seen as the set of point so that the sum of distances to two fixed points ( here $a$ and $-a$ )is constant, is an ellipse, where $a, -a$ are the foci of the ellipse, and $b$ is the minor axis. Once the major axis is chosen,   by definition, the minor axis is smaller (lengthwise); if the two are equal, you have a circle. Besides, $f^2= a^2 -b^2$, so you must have $a^2 -b^2 \geq 0 $.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hadn´t thought the problem geometrically but i got it. And sorry for not  answering all the questions but my english is not  very good. Thank you all you guys.

Comment: @AlbertoRuiz: Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

As you see by using the Triangle Inequality, the minimum possible value of $z\mapsto |z-a|+|z+a|$ is $2|a|$, and this map is an unbounded continuous function from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$.  What does this imply?

P.S. You thread's title says "$|a|\geq |b|$," which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I made the correction

Comment: My apology. The $\ge$ is a typo by me when I edited the question.